# Is the new mobile page too cluttered, or can we add back "last seen" and "member since?"

Tags: discussion, profile-page, mobile-web

On the new profile pages, some of the information that used to be on the top right of the old profile pages has been consciously omitted.

However, at least two of the old items were among the information about a user that I checked most frequently: "member since" and "last seen" (or something similar to these formulations). Both are valuable, in particular in meta discussions - I will address an experienced user differently from a new one, and after leaving a comment, it helps further discussion to know if the comment had a chance to be seen. There are other ways in which the two were useful to me.

Some of the information this used to be listed with is now under the line showing "questions" "answers" and "people reached." I think both items would fit neatly in a line below the lines I currently see there.

Site response to pointing this out in the main question requesting feedback to the recent changes was that adding this info would make the mobile version too cluttered.

I don't agree. Do you? Do you agree that it was useful info that should be added again to the mobile version too?